# What does the bracketed number mean in longplay titles?

Tags: terminology, longplay

I am referring to this:

```
NES Longplay [540] Takeshi No Chousenjou
              ^^^
```

I've had no luck researching this. From Google, to the World-Of-Longplays website, to Wikipedia's stub of an article on Longplays, there is no information about that 3-digit number.

I assume that the number is an ID that correlates with the corresponding game library for the system being played (allowing for up to 1,000 entries per console), but I could be wrong, and it doesn't seem right that it would only allow for 1,000, rather than 10,000 (seeing as the NES has over 700 games, which is dangerously close to 1,000), and can probably be outdone. I also have no idea where they get the number from. Chronological order? What if two games are released on the same date (such as Pokemon)?

The questions boil down to:

- What do the numbers mean?
- How are they determined?
- Assuming it's an ID, is there some sort of catalog listing the numbers and the games they identify?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I'm one of the admins for World of Longplays / www.longplays.org.

We are kind of a Video Game Museum documenting games

The number in the bracket is an ever increasing number that gets assigned to each longplay that is done for a specific system!

For example:

```
Amiga 500 Longplay [001] Another World     <- the 1st Amiga 500 longplay
Amiga 500 Longplay [002] Moonstone         <- the 2nd 
Amiga 500 Longplay [003] Rodland           <- the 3rd
Amiga 500 Longplay [004] Golden Axe        <- the 4th
Amiga 500 Longplay [005] Toki              <- the 5th
etc...
```

So for your example:

> NES Longplay [540] Takeshi No Chousenjou

It simply means it was the 540th longplay for NES and that there are 539 NES longplays before that one - it is just our way of keeping track of stuff :)

You could have figured it out by looking at our [playlists](https://www.youtube.com/user/cubex55/playlists)

And before someone asks what the (a) means - it means alternative recording - this is for games that have been recorded already, but the new recording offers something the old didn't - for example a 2 player longplay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, man! You answered the question(s) succinctly and effectively.

Comment: This is fantastic.  I emailed the World of Longplays YouTube channel in reference to this question to see if they could provide an answer, and they took the liberty to answer themselves within five minutes!  I think it's great how this turned out.

Comment: In that case, thanks @TimmyJim for starting the ball rolling!